# How to add UIView to ScrollView for Paging in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

Trying to add a UIView to a ScrollView that will scroll horizontally.

What my storyboard looks like:

[image]

I'd like to add a UIView to the UIScrollView and scroll horizontally.

How can I go about this?

Everytime I try it doesn't scroll.

Comment: You need to set the content size of the scroll view to make it scroll. What language are you using Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: I'm using Objective C